# Why can't HybridFox be used to manage Openstack?

Tags: cloud-computing

I have a question about using HybridFox to manage my Openstack "Cloud"    I have successfully installed Openstack and have AMI's up and running via commandline Euca2ools.  Can I use HybridFox or ElasticFox to manage my AMI's?   I am assuming that Openstack is EC2 compatible and simply uses REST calls to interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.6, Hybridfox officially supports Openstack. A Hybridfox user manual has also been added to the project's web page and can be downloaded from http://hybridfox.googlecode.com/files/Hybridfox_User_Manual_v1.pdf